# Google Ads has disapproved our website due to malicious or unwanted external links but we couldn't find the mentioned link (debysale.com) anywhere

Tags: adsense, malware

We run our website in wordpress betheme. We are trying to put AdSense ads on our website. For that, we contacted with google team, but from there end found a malicious or unwanted external links for which they are disapproving our website again and again. Previously we had malware which we removed recently. After that, We tried wordfence, google transparency site scan, secure wp and various other website scanners but found no malware or malicious external links.

They malicious link google mentioned : debysale[.]com

How to find and get rid of this malicious link? If anyone could assist, that would be very helpful.

I am attaching the reply of google with this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0czu.png)

For your help our website link is https://rkpl.com.bd/

Answer (score -1):

Open webpage in Google Chrome,  right click on page and press view source code, press crtl+f and search for the link.  Do this for each page on your website.

Comment: inspected each and every file, also tried to grep the keyword 'debysale' in the whole website files but found nothing @MikeMoy

Comment: what method did you use to inspect ?

Comment: i tried to grep the keyword from ssh and also dumped and scanned the full database and found nothing

Comment: and can you explain why you have not done what I told you to do in my answer ?

Comment: i have already done that before. You can check our website https://rkpl.com.bd

Comment: do you realise that debysale.com is not a registered domain, it does not exist